# Need solution For Dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

This is the input:

```
d={"mango":50,"apple":100,"banana":70} # this is the input
```

This should be the output:

```
{"mango":35,"apple":70,"banana":49}
```

I tried this:

```
f =  {i:int(i*0.7) for i in d}
```

How do I do this using dictionary compression only?

Comment: Please change the title. The title describes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
f = { k: int(v * 0.7) for k, v in d.items() }
```

Comment: Its giving output in float like 35.0 and 70.0 and i want the output in integer

Comment: Edited the answer to convert the output to integer, you may try again